# Why is the UI not updated and gives an error with several changes?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I update the information in the state, but when the action is called again, the error:

> "state.findIndex is not a function"

crashes. If I correctly understood, this is due to incorrect updating of the state. Where am I wrong? And why aren't UI rendered when upgrading?

```
import {contactList} from './../getContactsFromStorage/reducer'

export function saveChanges(state = contactList, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SAVE_CHANGES':
        const {contact} = action;
        console.log( action.id);
        let selectedIndex = state.findIndex(({id}) => id === action.id);
        let newState = [...state];
        newState[selectedIndex] = contact;
        console.log(newState.length, state.length);
        localStorage.clear();
        localStorage.setItem('done', 'true');
        for (let i = 0; i < newState.length - 1; i++) {
            localStorage.setItem(`contact${i}`, JSON.stringify(newState[i]));
        }
        return {...state, newState};
    default:
        return state;
}
}
```

contactList Structure:

```
export const contactList = [];

export function getContacts(state = contactList, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'LOAD_CONTACTS_FROM_STORAGE':
                for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length -1; i++) {
                    state.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem (`contact${i}`)))
                }
            return state;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Update

```
import {contactList} from './../getContactsFromStorage/reducer'

export function saveChanges(state = contactList, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SAVE_CHANGES':
        const {contact} = action;
        console.log( action.id);
        let selectedIndex = state.findIndex(({id}) => id === action.id);
        let newState = [...state];
        newState[selectedIndex] = contact;
        console.log(newState.length, state.length);
        localStorage.clear();
        localStorage.setItem('done', 'true');
        for (let i = 0; i < newState.length - 1; i++) {
            localStorage.setItem(`contact${i}`, JSON.stringify(newState[i]));
        }
        return [...newState];
    default:
        return state;
}
}
```

P.S. One issue has been resolved. But now, rerender is still not happening, and it seems that only one of the changes is saved in this connection

P.S.S. There was a question with the render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your state is an array, the return should be like

```
return [...state, ...newState];
```

Or simply

```
return [...newState];
```

If you don't want duplicates

Comment: Yes, now all saves remain valid. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the state here is an object and not an array that is why you are getting that error. Can you console log `state` before this line to confirm ?

`let selectedIndex = state.findIndex(({id}) => id === action.id);`

Comment: State is an array of objects